# Hyper-V Visual Studio Emulator for Android keeps overriding Virtual Switches

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, android, emulator

I am using Visual Studio Emulator for Android to deploy Android Emulators on a Hyper-V host server. These emulators need to have internet access.

Host server OS is Windows server 2016.

I have 3 network interfaces active:

- Mgmt interface to connect to the server.
- Internal interface used by Hyper-V.
- External interface used by Hyper-V.

Now for the problem, when I deploy a new emulator to the host, the software grabs all the active network interfaces, and makes them Hyper-V external interfaces, which results in not being able to manage the host remotely.(pings dropping, RDP not possible) After resetting the hyper-v/tcpip settings, everything turns back to normal. (pings arrive, RDP possible) Deploy a emulator again with the software, and the connections drops again.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: I don't understand your use of the word `adapter`. Are you referring to the Hyper-V virtual switches, as in external virtual switch, internal virtual switch, etc.?

Comment: I meant interface with adapter. Adapter=interface. I have editted the question. I am reffering to the virtual switches, as in external indeed.

Comment: I have the same problem. The emulator keeps recreating the vswitches from the free network adapters and using them, but not use the already exists vswitches associated with correct NICs.